# Reverse Nearest Neighbor Algorithm in Image Scaling in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is there a way to reverse this method of image scaling in Photoshop? This is an example of what I mean: http://tech-algorithm.com/uploads/nneighbor01.png

I need to reverse the process in order to come back to the original size.

Does Photoshop have this kind of feature?

Comment: nearest neibourhood is its own reverse

Comment: Thanks, after some attempts I understood that and I tried to give, replying to my own question, some more information about the right method to preserve the square shape of pixels during the process!

Comment: Consider accepting your own answer once the time counter allows you to so that the question does not become a zombie :)

Answer (score 2):

I managed to understand that the Nearest Neighbor Algorithm is reversible by definition. Example:

[image]

I just want to say that, in order to preserve quality, colors and square-shape for each pixel, you have to keep same aspect ratio. To do so, starting for example by a 16x16 image, you have to resize multiplying or dividing by multiples of two, otherwise you will obtain errors resizing like so

[image]

Comment: The multiples no not need to be 2x they can be 3x or whatever, but the reverse must be the same. A 16px > 48px >16px. But they indeed need to be a multiple.